# SSIS package execute application(. exe) file which is protected by password

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, msbi

I have a application (. Exe) file, 
At the time of running, it is asking the password to process.

My task is to run that exe file using SSIS package and pass the static password at the runtime.

Kindly help me to resolve my issue.

Comment: Can you please add more details about the context, I can't understand the relationship between SSIS and you .exe file

Comment: I have an exe application file. In general When I am running the file, it is asking for password to process . I want to create a package which will run the program file (like execute Process Task).But here the concern is how to pass the password at the runtime.

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of making the Arguments as an expression. In that expression you can pass the entire command line string including the password. This when you expose it via Package Configuration, it can then be made dynamic. Here is a link that shows how a SQL Server Package is used to zip a file with password which you can use to tweak for your package - [SSIS: How to Compress/Zip your file using 7-Zip?](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/24/syndicated/398/Posts/9961/ssis-how-to-compresszip-your-file-using-7-zip.aspx)